# How to select first element and last element of row in flex design?

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I select the first and last item in a row from a flexbox design?

For example, in this photo, the first and last in a row:

[image: sample]

Comment: not possible with CSS alone for a wrapping flexbox...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .first-row>p:first-child {
      color: red;
    }
    .first-row>p:last-child {
      color: green;
    }
```

```
<div class="first-row">
    <p>first</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>
<div class="second-row">
    <p>first</p>
    <p>second</p>
    <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Here I have taken `<p>` as the child. If you want you can have `div` as the child, then make sure to take flex off div and apply to `first-row` and `second-row` instead of the `div` tag. Also change `first-row>p` to `first-row>div`

Comment: I dynamicly create elements in div so I can not apply your method